# Drawing stars with nested loop javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, nested

I need to write porogram that will draw starslike below using nested depend loops:

```
 *
 **
 ***
 ****
 *****
```

I wrote code below and it works in console but in test I receive information:You have not used nested and dependent(!) for loops. Can you help and explain what I'm doing wrong?

```js
const n = 5
let stars = "";
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    stars = "";
    for (let j = i; j < n; j++) {
        stars = "*" + stars;
    }
    console.log(stars);
    }
```

Comment: Your code is perfectly fine and works. I've edited your post, so it can be run. If you want to flip your "tree" focus on inner loop. This part to be exact `let j = i`.

Comment: The inner loop should be `let j=0; j<=i; j++` or `let j=i; j>=0; j--`

Comment: Many thanks, the problem was that I had to flip "tree" which I did thanks to your suggestion:)